# Primitive of a continuous function over $\Bbb R$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, trigonometry

A continuous function over $\Bbb R$ has a primitive that is also continuous over $\Bbb R$.

However, it often happens with Mathematica and other CAS that the result is not continuous, especially with trigonometric integrals computed with the [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution). The result can't be correct because from a periodic integrand this substitution leads to a periodic primitive, while the primitive over $\Bbb R$ is not periodic in general.

For instance:

```
In[1]:= Integrate[3/(5 - 4 Cos[x]), x]
Out[1]= 2 ArcTan[3 Tan[x/2]]
```

**My question:**
Is there a way in Mathematica (an option, a package...) to obtain a continuous primitive in this case?

A correct one could be:

$$x + 2 \arctan\left(\frac{\sin x}{2 - \cos x}\right)$$

---

There are publications about this:

- D. J. Jeffrey, "[The Importance of Being Continuous](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2690852)"
- David J. Jeffrey, Albert D. Rich, "[The evaluation of trigonometric integrals avoiding spurious discontinuities](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/174603.174409)"

See also [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1942983/find-int-02-pi-frac15-4-cos-x-dx) on Math.SE.

I wonder if Mathematica has implementations of the methods mentioned in those articles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. First compute in a standard way

```
Integrate[3/(5-4 Cos[x]),x]
(*2 ArcTan[3 Tan[x/2]]*)
Plot[2 ArcTan[3 Tan[x/2]],{x,-10π,10π}]
```

[image]

Now try the [Rubi package](https://rulebasedintegration.org)

```
Get["Rubi`"]
Int[3/(5-4 Cos[x]),x]
(*x+2 ArcTan[Sin[x]/(2-Cos[x])]*)
Plot[x+2 ArcTan[Sin[x]/(2-Cos[x])],{x,-10π,10π}]
```

[image]

Comment: Also Integrate[3/(5 - 4 Cos[t]), {t, 0, x}, 
 Assumptions -> x \ [Element] Reals] does the job, producing 2 \ [Pi] IntegerPart[x/(2 \ [Pi])]+3 (\[Piecewise] -(2/3) (\ [Pi]-ArcTan[3 Tan[x/2]]) FractionalPart[x/(2 \ [Pi])]<=-(1/2)
2/3 ArcTan[3 Tan[x/2]] -(1/2)<FractionalPart[x/(2 \ [Pi])]<1/2
2/3 (\ [ Pi]+ArcTan[3 Tan[x/2]]) True

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.

Comment: @user64494 Not as simple, but indeed it works. It's the natural way to make the standard solution continuous by hand, by adding a constant on each subinterval. I thought I tried, but I probably forgot the assumption.

Comment: Rubi works also on the algebraic case of [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm), which is quite impressive: `Int[x/Sqrt[x^4 + 10 x^2 - 96 x - 71], x]` (example from Wikipedia).

Answer (score 2):

`Integrate[f[x], x]` gives an antiderivative whose derivative is generically equal to `f[x]`. From the docs:

> For indefinite integrals, `Integrate` tries to find results that are correct for almost all values of parameters.

A primitive function of a continuous function $f$ such as the OP seeks is given by
$$F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) \; dt \,.$$

```
prim = Integrate[3/(5 - 4 Cos[t]), {t, 0, x}, 
  Assumptions -> -Infinity < x < Infinity]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[prim, {x, -30, 30}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It's enough Assumptions -> -Infinity < x or Assumptions -> x < Infinity in the above. This is the same as x \ [Element] Reals